# Do homeomorphic manifolds with boundary have homeomorphic interiors?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M, N$ be manifolds with boundary and $f: M \rightarrow N$ be a homeomorphism. I want to show that $\text{Int}M$ is homeomorphic to $\text{Int}N$. I think I have most of the proof but it relies on an assumption which I don't know if it's valid or not.

I first assume that $f(\text{Int}M) = \text{Int}N$. I don't have a proof of this, and as far as I know there could be counterexamples. But with this assumption the rest of the proof becomes very easy since f is the homeomorphism:

$f$ restricted to $\text{Int}M$ will clearly still be bijective, and a set is open in $M$ iff it is open in $\text{Int}M$. Same for $N$ and $\text{Int}N$. Thus continuity of $f$ and its inverse follow immediately, and so $\text{Int}M$ and $\text{Int}N$ are homeomorphic.

What about the assumption I made? Are there any counterexamples?

Comment: Your assumption is valid. The proof for topological manifolds I know of uses algebraic topology. Locally at interior points the punctured neighborhoods are spheres. Locally at boundary points, the puncture neighborhoods are disks.

Comment: So it's always true that a homeomorphism maps interior to interior?

Comment: @jgon semi-spheres (half balls) instead of disks.

Comment: The fact that $f(\operatorname{int}(M))=\operatorname{int}N$ for topological manifold homeomorphisms follows from the [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), which, as @jgon mentioned, uses algebraic topology. For topologial manifolds and $C^1$ diffeomorphisms you can use the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Manifolds).

Comment: @LuizCordeiro You should give an official answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $f(\operatorname{int} M )=\operatorname{int} N$ for topological manifold homeomorphisms follows from the [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), which, as @jgon mentioned in the comments, uses tools from Algebraic Topology. See [Elementary proof of topological invariance of dimension using Brouwer's fixed point and invariance of domain theorems?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197640/elementary-proof-of-topological-invariance-of-dimension-using-brouwers-fixed-po) for good references.

Here are some details: Let $x\in\operatorname{int}M$. Taking small coordinate charts around $x$ and $f(x)$, and composing with the homeomorphism $f$, we find a homeomorphism $f'$ between an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and an open subset $V$ of some $\mathbb{R}^m$, or an open subset $V$ of a half-space of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Restricting (the inverse of) this homeomorphism to the interior of $V$ (in $\mathbb{R}^m$), we see, by invariance of domain, that $m=n$ (see [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1197662/58818) to linked question above). But then invariance of domain itself implies that $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $f(x)$ is interior to $N$.

This proves $f(\operatorname{int}M)\subseteq\operatorname{int}N$. The same argument with the inverse $f^{-1}$ gives the reverse inclusion.

---

The same type of argument works with $C^1$ diffeomorphisms between $C^1$ manifolds, using the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Manifolds), which can be proven with relatively elementary real analysis and linear algebra.